# Issue with dynamically populating address fields with Gravity Forms

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

Using the **gform_pre_render_** hook I receive the error when attempting to populate the default values:

> Fatal error : Uncaught Error: Attempt to assign property
> “defaultValue” on array in…

This is the code I am using:

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_'.$gravity_form_id, 'ebd_populate_form_with_data' );
function ebd_populate_form_with_data( $form ){
    $post_id_cid = false;
    if(!empty($_GET['cid'])) {
        $post_id_cid = base64_decode(urldecode($_GET['cid']));
    }
    $address_fields = array(
        'address',
        'city',
        'state',
        'zip'
    );
    foreach( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {
        $input_name = $field['inputName'];

        if ($field['type'] == 'address' && is_array($field['inputs'])) {
            foreach ($field['inputs'] as $address_field) {
                $input_name = $address_field['name']; // why is this not inputName?
                if ($input_name && in_array($input_name, $address_fields)) {
                    $current_value = get_post_meta($post_id_cid, $input_name, true);
                    if ($current_value) {
                        $address_field->defaultValue = $current_value; // error
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    return $form;
}
```

The slugs in the **$address_fields** array are the same as the slugs in my custom post type for storing the data. Also, I am using these slugs in their respective fields in the “Parameter Name” fields after checking “Allow field to be dynamically populated” when creating the form.

Setting **->defaultValue** works with other text based fields. Why is it not working for addresses? Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code fixed my issue:

```
   if ( $field->type == 'address' && is_array( $field->inputs ) ) {
        foreach ( $field->inputs as &$input ) {
            $input_name = rgar( $input, 'name' );
            if ( $input_name && in_array( $input_name, $address_fields ) ) {
                $current_value = get_post_meta( $post_id_cid, $input_name, true );
                if ( $current_value ) {
                    $input['defaultValue'] = $current_value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Glad you solved it. So what was actually wrong, and what did you change? It looks like the & on the inner loop iterator, and assigning by [] not -> ?

Comment: The way that the data is structured for address fields is different than with normal text fields. The individual address fields are arrays instead of objects. It can be a little confusing because it lets you access objects with array notation sometimes.